# trying to process a Thymeleaf registration form with Spring Security 6 -> 403 on POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm new to Spring Boot and am trying to create a simple registration + login. However whenever I try to submit data with a POST request, the request gets blocked (403) and I'm not getting redirected to the success page. Since the request gets blocked, this results later on in a Null pointer Exception when I try to validate the submitted input.

Looking through other posts a common problem seemed to be csrf protection, which I explicitly disabled. Another common issue among other posts was that the correct authorization wasn't granted, I tried to do so with `.permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`. Since to my understanding I explicitly enabled all requests for "/register", I expected to at least get the credentials as output at the debug messages in the Controller.

The registration form;

```html
        <form th:action="@{register}" method="post" th:object="${registrationRequest}">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="emailInput" class="form-label"></label>
                <input th:field="*{email}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('email')} ? 'is-invalid'" type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="usernameInput" class="form-label"></label>
                <input th:field="*{name}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('name')} ? 'is-invalid'" type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameInput" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="passwordInput" class="form-label"></label>
                <input th:field="*{password}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('password')} ? 'is-invalid'" type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="passwordRepeatInput" class="form-label"></label>
                <input th:field="*{passwordRepeat}" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordRepeat')} ? 'is-invalid'" type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordRepeatInput" placeholder="Password confirmation">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-custom">Sign up!</button>
        </form>
```

The routing in the Controller;

```
    @RequestMapping(value="register")
    public String showRegisterPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("registrationRequest", new RegistrationRequest());
        return "user/user-add";
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value="register")
    public String processRegisterRequest(@ModelAttribute RegistrationRequest registrationRequest, BindingResult result) {
    
        System.out.println("DEBUG: " + registrationRequest.getName() + registrationRequest.getEmail() + registrationRequest.getPassword());
        System.out.println(result.getAllErrors());
    
        userService.register(registrationRequest);
        return "user/registration-success";
    }
```

The likely misconfigured SecurityFilterChain;

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/register",
                        "/login",
                        "/css/style.css")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }
```

The console error output;

```
2023-11-25T17:50:38.436+01:00 DEBUG 11889 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-25T17:50:47.352+01:00 DEBUG 11889 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /register
2023-11-25T17:50:47.354+01:00 DEBUG 11889 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /register
DEBUG: nullnullnull
[]
DEBUG: nullnull
2023-11-25T17:50:47.360+01:00 DEBUG 11889 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-25T17:50:47.361+01:00 ERROR 11889 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "password" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "password" is null
```

EDIT

added class RegistrationRequest;

```
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString

public class RegistrationRequest {
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String passwordRepeat;
}
```

Comment: @Toerktumlare Sorry, I've added the requested Class and added the schema. Now the browser console doesn't display the 403 for the request anymore, however the credentials still aren't passed.

Comment: have you defined the templating engine and defined how your viewes are served etc?

Comment: Found the mistake, there was just the @Setter in RegistrationRequest missing, I'll post an answer around your comment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there were 2 problems in my code;

1. Based on the comment of @Toerktumlare; To resolve the 403 Error I needed to add `.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())` to the SecurityFilterChain.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/","/register","/login","/css/style.css")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return http.build();
}
```

2. The `@Setter` annotation in RegistrationRequest was missing, hence the values for the attributes couldn't be set.

```
import lombok.*;
    
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
    
public class RegistrationRequest {
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String passwordRepeat;
}
```